# Searching a number from array without using API

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am new with Java.
This is the code i wrote for searching a number(prompt value) from array.
It won't find a match number, but it works when i change `if(values[i]==number[i])` to `if(values[i]==number[1])`

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int[] number = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};


    //Convert string to int
    int[] values = new int[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        values[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<number.length; j++){

            if(values[i]==number[i]){
            //if(values.equals(number[1])){

                System.out.println("Number is found");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Number is not found");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Change your if statement to `values[i]==number[j]`

Comment: Sorry to put wrong input value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
if(values[i]==number[i])
```

to

```
if(values[i]==number[j])
```

Furthermore I would use a boolean so that you don't output a line at every iteration of the loop, but just at the end of the analysis of each value in args.

It would end up to be something like :

```
boolean found;
for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    found = false;
    for(int j=0; j<number.length; j++){
        if(values[i]==number[j]){
            found = true
        }
    }
    if(found){               
        System.out.println("Number is found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Number is not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where i did wrong, because it still can not find match number after i changed i to j.

Comment: How are you running your program? What is your input?

Comment: Sorry, i was putting the wrong input value which input value for another question.

Comment: So everything's good?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are searching value `value[i]` in array `number`. And you are scanning the array `number` by using `j`. Try this:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int[] number = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


//Convert string to int
int[] values = new int[args.length];
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    values[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    boolean flag=false;
    for(int j=0; j<number.length; j++){

        if(values[i]==number[j]){
            System.out.println("Number is found");
            flag=true;
            break;  // Since we found number hence move out from inner loop
        }

    }
     if(!flag)
          System.out.println("Number is not found");

    }
 }
```